# Physical memory address space

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, memory-hardware, virtual-memory, paging

When you address physical memory, in the kernel, is it just another value like `0xf78f9` just like virtual addresses (and the only thing that is different is that the processor is in real-mode)? Is it all contiguous (from my understanding it is a concatenation of the Physical Page Number and the Page Offset)?

How can you determine the lengths of your address space? Does this change with memory-mapped I/O if it overlaps with your physical address space?

Comment: What do you mean by physical memory being "just another value" ? What do you mean by the value being contiguous ?

Comment: Of course physical addresses are just numbers. The BIOS tells the operating system how much memory is installed, and what the addresses are.

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be contiguous addresses? i.e., like the virtual address space -> you can address Physical addresses from 0 to 0xffffff or whatever the limit is. I think maybe it's not, and maybe memory-mapped i/o may conflict with this.